# How do I configure Emacs html-mode to behave like TextMate's default HTML bundle?

Tags: html, emacs, textmate

A friend of mine is considering switching to Emacs from TextMate.  He is used to TextMate's default HTML editing mode which has 4-space tab stops and inserts tab characters (i.e. it does no auto-indenting by default).  It also allows completion of open HTML tags with "`Cmd-Shift->`".  Any ideas?

Comment: Ack, I was inaccurate above.  I didn't mean actual tab characters but rather 4 spaces in place of a tab character.  Apologies for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think these settings should do the trick:

```
(defun my-html-mode-hook ()
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (define-key html-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'my-insert-tab)
  (define-key html-mode-map (kbd "C->") 'sgml-close-tag))

(defun my-insert-tab (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (insert-tab arg))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my-html-mode-hook)
```

An explanation of the settings in `'my-html-mode-hook` is as follows:

- set the tab width to 4
- force tabs to be inserted (as opposed to spaces)
- force the `TAB` key to insert a tab (by default it is bound to do indentation, not just insertion of tabs
- `'sgml-close-tag` is the command that inserts a close tag for you, and this setting gets you the keybinding you want

I'm having a bit of a brain freeze and couldn't figure out the simple way to have the `TAB` key insert a TAB character, so I wrote my own.  I don't know why a binding to `'self-insert-command` didn't work (that's what normal keys are bound to).

The last line just adds the setup function to the `'html-mode-hook`.  The key bindings really only need to be run once (as opposed to every time html-mode is enabled), but this is a little easier to read than using `'eval-after-load`.  It's use is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm ingrained into using ctrl-z and meta-z to scroll-up/scroll/down single lines.  (This was standard, I think in emacs like in the 80s or something.)  I had to add that to my custom.el in XEmacs 21.5.29, but then found the customization was being overriden by the HTML major mode.  Trey's mechanism was exactly what I needed to get it working again.  Bravo Trey.  There's nothing like having the window disappear while you're scrolling to destroy your flow...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about emacs's HTML modes specifically, but I can answer about general editing:

- by default, Emacs doesn't autoindent, so nothing to do here.
- Emacs preserves tab characters, unless you explicitely ask them changed (check out `tabify` and `untabify`).  Their width is determined by the buffer-local `tab-width` variable.  `M-x set-variable`, `(setq...)`, customize at will.
- you should be able to get the behavior you want with the tab key by setting `indent-line-function` to `tab-to-tab-stop`, setting `tab-stop-list` to `(4 8 12 16...)` and `indent-tabs-mode` to `t`.

Setting `indent-tabs-mode` allows Emacs to insert tab characters when indenting.  The `tab-to-tab-stop` is a form of indentation that only goes to specific positions in the line, which we set to match the expected behavior of the tab characters by setting `tab-stop-list` to the multiples of 4.

About completion, the only thing my muscle memory tells me is "`C-c C-e`", but I don't remember for sure which major mode it's supposed to go with.  The closest I see in the list is `sgml-close-tag`, bound to `C-c /`

A bit of politics: don't use tab characters, especially if you use widths not equal to 8.  It only results in unpredictable results